# Python and MongoDB Convert data type from string to long

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am new to mongodb and pymongo. Have a small clarification in converting the field datatype from string to long. Fieldname = sc_2g

The following is working fine using mongoshell.

```
db.collection.aggregate({$set: {sc_g: { $toLong: "$sc_g" }}},{$out:"collection"})
```

but i need equivalent in python. Can anyone help..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aggregation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/aggregation.html) too in pymongo.

```
pipeline = {"$set": {"sc_g": { "$toLong": "$sc_g" }}}, {"$out":"collection"}
list(db.collection.aggregate(pipeline))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot AG. I have tried the code with bit modification. 
Kindly check, if this can help, as I can see, the code is running without error but no updates on the collection.

pipeline = {"$set": {"sc_g": { "$toLong": "$sc_g" }}}, {"$out":"collection"}
db.collection.aggregate(list(pipeline))